# How to change the color of a listbox item containing a certain string?

Tags: c#, listboxitem

I don't really know the syntax to change colors of certain listbox items.
I want to change the color of all the items inside a listbox containing a certain string.

Code:

```
string statusG = "Status: (1)";
        for (int i = 0; i < lstBoxResidencies.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstBoxResidencies.Items[i].ToString().Contains(statusG))
            {
                lstBoxResidencies.Items[i]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **How to change the color of a listbox item containing a certain string** and this outcome can be achieved by changing the `DrawMode` property of the `ListBox` (for example, to `OwnerDrawFixed`). Here I have taken the [Microsoft Example for the DrawItem Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=netframework-4.8#examples) and made some minor changes to fit your question:

```
private void InitializeListBox()
{
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(new Object[]
        { "Normal-1", "Status-1", "Normal-2" });
    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ListBox1_DrawItem);
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var value = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();

    // Custom-draw the background
    // Here is where you look the the string value.
    if(value.Contains("Status"))
    {
        // Draw custom background
        using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Draw default background
        e.DrawBackground();
    }

    // The text must still be drawn.
    // There aren't any real changes so use standard code to do this.
    using (var textBrush = new SolidBrush(listBox1.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(value, listBox1.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds);
    }
}
```

This shows the result of the custom draw:
[image: Custom highlight graphic]

Comment: 1) You shouldn't override the `OnHandleCreated` method this way. The method might be called multiple times at runtime. For example, when you set a property that calls the `RecreateHandle` method. Meaning, the same block of `if (!DesignMode)` might be executed again and maybe again. Move that to the `ctor` or the `Form.Load` event. 2) Use the `TextRenderer.DrawText(...)` method to draw strings over controls and keep the `Graphics.DrawString` for the images business. 3) For the ListBox, ComboBox, CheckedListBox controls, use the `GetItemText(...)` method to get the text of an item.

Comment: Well, I'll give you something to try. Keep your code as is, add a Button, handle the Click event to set a property, say for example to toggle the layout through the `RightToLeft` property which causes handle recreation. Examine the result yourself.

Comment: Another try-it-out, Derive a new class from `ListBox`, override the `OnHandleCreated` method and set `DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;` property which its setter in the base class calls the `RecreateHandle` method. Good luck :)